# Concat the second part of multiple arrays

Tags: python, numpy, stack

I want to concat 2 arrays with same shapes as follow:

```
array1= (1230000,32)
array2= (1230000,32)
array3= (1230000,32)
```

I want my result become

```
res1= array1+array2: (1230000,64)
res2= array1+array2+array3: (1230000,96)
```

I have tried

```
res1 = np.stack((array1,array2),axis=-1)
print('result 1',res1.shape)
```

But ths didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You had the axis right, however what you're looking for is [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html). The [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) function will create a new dimension, while `np.concatenate` uses an existing one:

```
res1 = np.concatenate((array1, array2), axis=1) # shape (1230000, 64)
```

Or for any number of input arrays defined as a *tuple* (or *list*):

```
arrays = array1, array2, array3
res2 = np.concatenate(arrays, axis=1) # shape (1230000, 96)
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.hstack` is what you are looking for which horizontally stacks arrays fed to it:

```
res1 = np.hstack((array1,array2))  #(1230000,64)
res2 = np.hstack((array1,array2,array3))  #(1230000,96)
```

Answer (score -2):

The best option would be to define a function that performs what you need. Something like this:

```
array1= [1230000,32] #Change to array to avoid inmutable tuple
array2= [1230000,32] #Change to array to avoid inmutable tuple
array3= [1230000,32] #Change to array to avoid inmutable tuple


def sumArrays(arraysToSum = []):
    result = [0, 0]
    for arrayToSum in arraysToSum:
        result[0] = arrayToSum[0]
        result[1] += int(arrayToSum[1])
    return result
        
print(sumArrays([array1, array2, array3]))

Output: [1230000, 96]
```

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the quesiton.  He is asking how to concat arrays of the shape he provided to the desired shape.  Also, you should never use a mutable object as a default argument.